# how to implement `kubectl create -f pod.yaml` using kubernetes go client library

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I have a folder with name "myspec" which has some kube-spec files , let's say

- pod.yaml , service.yaml,  secret.yaml

when I run the command **"kubectl create -f myspec"** it creates everything , pod , service and secret.

Now I wish to perform the same thing using kubernetes go client library.

Comment: i am trying to unmarshal the pod json to an object so that i can pass the object(*v1.Pod) to the function clientset.CoreV1().Pods("default").Create(*v1.Pod)
is there any other way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the previous poster, meant to post This:

1) You first convert the string to bytes.

2) Then serialize it to a pod.

3) Then create the pod like any other object.

This can be done, without loss of generality, for Pods, Services, ReplicationControllers, Deployments, ConfigMaps, Secrets, and any other kubernetes API object.

**example**

```
func CreatePodFromYaml(podAsYaml string, ns string) error {
    var p v1.Pod
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(podAsYaml), &p)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    pod, poderr := kubernetesConfig().CoreV1().Pods(ns).Create(&p)
    if poderr != nil {
        return poderr
    }
    fmt.Printf("Created Pod %q.\n", pod.GetObjectMeta().GetName())
    return nil
}
```

To compile this code, you'll also need to make the kubernetesConfig object:

```
func kubernetesConfig() *kubernetes.Clientset {
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", "/$HOME/.kube/config")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    return clientset
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am able to create the pod using kubernetes go client library , 
i am passing json file and namespace name  to the function and it unmarhshal to the v1.Pod object and call the create function as below

```
func createPod(b []byte, ns string) {

  var p v1.Pod.Name
  err := json.Unmarshal(b, &p)
  if err != nil {

  }
  pod, poderr := kubernetesConfig().CoreV1().Pods(ns).Create(&p)
  pod.
  if poderr != nil {
    fmt.Println(poderr.Error())
  } else {
    fmt.Printf("Created Pod %q.\n", pod.GetObjectMeta().GetName())
  }
}

func kubernetesConfig() *kubernetes.Clientset {
config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", "/$HOME/.kube/config")
if err != nil {
fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)

if err != nil {
fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
return clientset
}
```